# How can I extract the 'logical_test' from an if statement in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm putting together an excel spreadsheet for calculations, and I need to be able to show the formulas to go with the decisions, for the most part its pretty straight forward, but When I come to an 'if' formula in an excel cell, I don't want to show the value_if_true and value_if_false... Just the logical_test value.

**Example:**

Formula is: `=if(and(5<=A1, A1<=10),"Pass", "Fail");`

Result will be: `"and(5<=A1, A1<=10)"`

I need to be able to work with complex logical tests which may include nested if statements, so just splitting at the commas won't work reliably. Similarly the value_if_true and value_if_false statements could also contain if statements.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you planning on representing the logical test?  Seems like it will be tricky if there can be multiple nested levels.

Comment: It will also get very tricky if there is a formula such as `=A2+5*C5+B6/IF(X3=IF(Y2=9,4,0),5,7)`

Comment: That's the next challenge. It'll be easy enough for simple if statements, I'm going to use a different function to generate a user readable equation (for users who aren't excel gurus).

Comment: I'm not sure you can extract a single stand-alone logical test from a nested set of logical tests, which together may not evaluate to just True/False, but to one of multiple outcomes.

Answer (score 2):

If have clear understanding of what you asking for, then you can use something like this (shall be used only with `IF()` statement :

```
Function extrIf(ByVal ifstatement As Range) As String

Dim S$, sRev$, x%, k
S = Replace(Replace(ifstatement.Formula, "IF(", "\"), "),", ")|")

sRev = StrReverse(S)

If InStr(1, sRev, "|") > InStr(1, sRev, "\") Or InStr(1, sRev, "|") = 0 Then
    x = InStr(1, StrReverse(Left(sRev, InStr(1, sRev, "\"))), ",") - 1
    S = Mid(S, 1, Len(S) - InStr(1, sRev, "\") + x) & "|"
End If

sRev = ""

For Each k In Split(S, "|")
    If k <> "" Then
        If k Like "*\*" Then
            sRev = sRev & ", " & Mid(k, InStr(1, k, "\") + 1, 999)
        End If
    End If
Next

extrIf = Mid(sRev, 3, 999)

End Function
```

example:

[image]

test:

[image]

Maybe this is not complete solution for you, but I think it might give you right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If the cell formula starts with an `If` statement then you can return the logic test (starting after the first open parenthesis) by determining the position of the first comma where the sum of the previous open parenthesis - the sum previous closed = 0.

### Formulas

[image]

```
Function ExtractIfTest(Target As Range) As String
    Dim ch As String, s As String
    Dim openP  As Long
    Dim x As Long
    s = Target.formula

    For x = 5 To Len(s)
        ch = Mid(s, x, 1)
        If Mid(s, x, 1) = "(" Then
            openP = openP + 1
        ElseIf Mid(s, x, 1) = ")" Then
            openP = openP - 1
        ElseIf Mid(s, x, 1) = "," And openP = 0 Then
            ExtractIfTest = Mid(s, 5, x - 12)
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

### Results

[image]

There might be instances where the is a comma without parenthesis `A1,B1`. If this happens simple escape them with parenthesis `(A1,B1)`

Comment: That's not quite what I'm after. I need to extract the logical test so I can then use it in a different function (e.g. MakeReadable(logical_test as string)). 
But you might be on to something by defining the logical_test more clearly. What if I could just wrap the logical_test in curly braces or something like that? (I can't... I checked).
Another thought is that I could iterate through a formula string and create a string of characters to look out for (open brackets, and quotation marks), and only accept the first comma once all open brackets and quotation marks have been accounted for...

Comment: Will the logic test always be wrapped in an `If()` statement?

Comment: by logical_test I'm referring to the first argument of an if() statement. 
![Image](http://i429.photobucket.com/albums/qq13/hickoz_bro/Capture_1.png)

Comment: @GerHick I updated my answer to extract the first part of an if statement.  I didn't realize that you wouldn't get a notification of an updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've written an UDF that extract any of the parameters of the target formula. It's close to the one in Thomas answer, but more global and takes into account strings that can enclose commas or parenthesis.

```
Function ExtractFormulaParameter(Target As Range, Optional Position As Long = 1) As Variant
    Dim inString As Boolean
    Dim formula As String
    Dim st As Long, sp As Long, i As Long, c As String
    Dim parenthesis As Long, comma As Long
    formula = Target.formula
    st = 0: sp = 0
    If Position <= 0 Then ExtractFormulaParameter = CVErr(xlErrValue): Exit Function

    For i = 1 To Len(formula)
        c = Mid$(formula, i, 1)
        If inString Then
            If c = """" Then
                inString = False
            End If
        Else
            Select Case c
            Case """"
                inString = True
            Case "("
                parenthesis = parenthesis + 1
                If parenthesis = 1 And Position = 1 Then
                    st = i + 1
                End If
            Case ")"
                parenthesis = parenthesis - 1
                If parenthesis = 0 And sp = 0 Then sp = i: Exit For
            Case ","
                If parenthesis = 1 Then
                    comma = comma + 1
                    If Position = 1 And comma = 1 Then sp = i: Exit For
                    If Position > 1 And comma = Position - 1 Then st = i + 1
                    If Position > 1 And comma = Position Then sp = i: Exit For
                End If
            Case Else
            End Select
        End If
    Next i

    If st = 0 Or sp = 0 Then
        ExtractFormulaParameter = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    Else
        ExtractFormulaParameter = Mid$(formula, st, sp - st)
    End If
End Function
```

By default it returns the first parameter, but you can also return the second or the third, and it should work with any formula.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies all. I thought about this more, and ended up coming up with a similar solution to those posted above - essentially string manipulation to extract the text where we expect to find the logical test.

Works well enough, and I'm sure I could use it to extract further logical tests from substrings too.